# AngularJS filter includes negative number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

When I filter an array of object with a number something like:

```
$scope.users = [{name:'John', id:-1},
                         {name:'Mary', id:1},
                         {name:'Mike', id:2},
                         {name:'Adam', id:3}];

var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {id: $scope.target});
```

If target = 1, the selected result will include John and Mary. But I only want the exactly same id which is Mary with id 1 to be included. Why does it include negative numbers? How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the third parameter of the filter which is the comparator to be true

```
$scope.users = [{name:'John', id:-1},
                         {name:'Mary', id:1},
                         {name:'Mike', id:2},
                         {name:'Adam', id:3}];

var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {id: $scope.target}, true);
```

`true` is a shorthand for:

```
function(actual, expected) { 
    return angular.equals(actual, expected)
} // This is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9cloYIjJeT7uP8jaIaj?p=preview).